# Creating a directory at /Users/Shared/ - using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am using the following code to create a directory in /Users/Shared/ to share data of my application between all users. When i run the code gotthe below output.

> 2019-03-08 19:41:41.751418+0530 MyApp[7224:488397] Couldn't create document directory
>
> 2019-03-08 19:41:41.754026+0530 MyApp[7224:488397] Document directory is file:///Users/Appname

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if let tDocumentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .userDirectory, in: .localDomainMask).first {
        let filePath =  tDocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Appname")
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: filePath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                NSLog("Couldn't create document directory")
            }
        }
        NSLog("Document directory is \(filePath)")
     }
```

I don't why this error occured. How this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the log messages carefully.

You are trying to create the folder `file:///Users/Appname` which is **not** in `/Users/Shared`. You have to append `"Shared/Appname"`.

And you are encouraged to use the URL related API of FileManager (and less confusing variable names )

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let userDirectory = try! fileManager.url (for: .userDirectory, in: .localDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let folderURL = userDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Shared/Appname")
if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: folderURL.path) {
    do {
        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't create document directory", error)
    }
}
print("Document directory is \(folderURL)")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!. But when i create a directory in .applicationSupportDirectory using the same code the following error  occurred.  Why the app can't get permission to write files in application support directory in localdomainmask?

Comment: Couldn't create document directory
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 
"You don’t have permission to save the file “mymac” in the folder “Application Support”." 
UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Library/Application Support/mymac, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c5e970 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"}}

Document directory is file:///Library/Application%20Support/mymac

Comment: `/Library/Application Support` (local domain) belongs to the root user (`system`). You have only access to the folder in `userDomainMask`. For the local domain you need root privileges.

Comment: Is it possible to create folder in /Library/Application Support (local domain) ?

Comment: Not in a sandboxed app, otherwise only with a privileged helper

Comment: Ok. How privileged helper helps to create a create folder in /Library/Application Support ? Please explain me little bit about it. I am new to macOS development.

Comment: A privileged helper is not trivial and cannot be described in one paragraph. Please search.

Comment: Add 'com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write' entitlement to you app Entitlements and specify /Library/Application Support forlder in that entitlement. Then use let pw = getpwuid(getuid()) to get the User folder path and create an URL like this: URL(fileURLWithFileSystemRepresentation: pw.pointee.pw_dir, isDirectory: true, relativeTo: nil). Just remember that you have to explain to App Store review team why your app has to use the 'com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write' entitlement.